# Visual Studio calling method placed in Form by otside class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, class, namespaces

Before i start i'd like to say that i know there are similar post on this forum. Unfortunately in my case they did not work. I'm sure it's my fault. I hope you can help me.

So here is my case:

I had wrote windows form, which works like terminal. I've got function that adds text to this terminal. I want to call this function from inside custom class.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace terminal
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Test testClass = new Test() ;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            terminal(textBox1.Text);
        }

        public void terminal(string text)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(text);
            richTextBox1.AppendText("\n");
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        Form1.terminal("sample tekst");
    }
}
```

And this thing don't work. When i start debugging, i can see memory going up, but no form appears. My problem here is that i can't acces function addToLog(); from class LoadSomeFiles. Visual Studio underlines whole line

```
Form1.terminal("sample tekst");
```

in red. I'm sorry if i wrote this kind of weird. I'm newbie.

Suorce files: [Program](http://speedy.sh/cTG5a/terminal.7z)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This doesn't even compile, let alone demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Whole program is more than 600 rows long. I can't just put him here. It won't be readable. I posted simplified idea of my program.

Comment: and when you call what?

Comment: Just create an [mcve]. And go over the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to address other points that can help to get your question answered.

Comment: If you have shared functionalities between forms/classes, I would recommand make a new static class that contains those functions as static, so you can use it wherever you need.

Comment: Give me a second. I'm rewriting program to more compact version. I update maint post in a while.

Comment: That still won't compile. You can't statically call `terminal()` if it is not static.

Comment: When I make terminal static void everything inside gets red. Could you show me you way of fixing this?

Comment: If you want to call a method on the form, you need to have an instance of the form, or the method needs to be static - which would then mean you can't then affect the controls on the form, which belong to an instance. Your question doesn't make clear how `Form1` and `Test` relate - e.g. is the instance of Test created by form1, or by another form, or somewhere else? Is there a Form1 running while test is running?

Comment: Instance of Test is running inside Form1. Sorry for not mentioning this. I forgot. User uses Form1 GUI  (clicking buttons),  then Form1 is calling functions  from Test. If Test can't do what is was told, then it should show massage in terminal by calling function terminal();.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an instance of the object u need. In this case the Form1 object. 
Then you can access it like you did.

Here is what i mean:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.terminal("sample text");
```

Hope this helps you.